# The SetJointPositions function is not working in Gazebo 1.2

Tags: gazebo-1.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use `set_model_configurations` to move the joints arbitrarily in Gazebo 1.20. The problem is that when I set the configuration, the model didn't move at all! I look inside the codes of `setModelCofiguration` and found that the `SetJointPositions` function is probably not working. Did anyone notice this problem or I did something wrong? Any suggestions? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/249/the-setjointpositions-function-is-not-working-in-gazebo-1.2/) by [shuai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/91/shuai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-20**:
How are you calling `SetJointPositions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I did something similar in a c++ model plugin.

I have a private member variable of type

```
private: physics::JointController * j2_controller;
```

Which is initialized in the Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf) function as follows

```
// Initialize the JointController with the model pointer
    this->j2_controller = new physics::JointController(_parent);
```

In, for instance, the OnUpdate() function, I have code that boils down to this:

```
double angle(0.0);
std::string j2name("j2name");    
j2_controller->SetJointPosition(j2name,angle);
```

However, my model is dynamic--I'm not sure if this would work to animate a static model.  Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Gwen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/52/gwen/) with karma: 81 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2